# Ruby HTTPClient set content_type to json

Tags: ruby

How can I set the content type of JSON for [HTTPClient](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/HTTPClient)? This is an embarassingly simple question but I can't seem to find a headers hash to use. The other option I see is [JSONClient](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/JSONClient) but I'm not sure how to access the object as I get the error `NameError: uninitialized constant JSONClient`.

My gemfile is `gem 'httpclient'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
require 'jsonclient'
```

Then you can use JSONClient just as HTTPClient.

Answer (score 2):

In the [doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/HTTPClient:initialize) you see that the `new` method accept a Hash of args and you can pass a header with  `Content-type:application/json`

ALSO, a tip: This [site](https://webhook.site) let you test your requests (oh, and don't forget to remove the s of http, lol)

```
a = HTTPClient.new({proxy: "http://webhook.site/052626ab-3128-41c5-a5a5-799a2f5ecd94", header: "Content-type:application/json"})
a.post("http://webhook.site/052626ab-3128-41c5-a5a5-799a2f5ecd94",{"msg": "olar"})
```

Answer (score 0):

use either:

```
require 'httpclient'
HTTPClient.new.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos', nil, ['Accept', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'])
```

or

```
require 'httpclient'
JSONClient.new.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
```